# Store Values from a Dynamic Cell Elsewhere in the Spreadsheet - Building a Database with Excel/Google spreadsheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, google-spreadsheets

I have a list of values that updates as new data becomes available on a website using importXML (cells A1-A25).  I want to store those values elsewhere in the spreadsheet so that when the values update I have the new values and the old values.

Currently when the values update I lose the old values.  What is the easiest way to do this in google spreadsheets? (or in excel if not possible in google spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do this in Excel. One is to use a macro, but macros introduce other issues. The second uses a paste special operation.

- Highlight the A1-A25 cells.
- Copy the cells with a ctlr-c
- Click on where you want the data to stay and use a paste special value

Paste special value can be done by
(Alt) E-S-V
or using the mouse on the home ribbon, click on the drop down arrow beneath paste then select paste special then values